# How to return data correctly when navigate Back in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have try with 2 page in my project : MainPage.xaml and DetailPage.xaml.

In MainPage.xaml.cs, I set an event to navigate to DetailPage

```
private void Import_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage));
}
```

and in DetailPage.xaml.cs, I set an event to NavigateBack with parameter :

```
private async void DoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTarget.RenderAsync(swapChainPanel);
            IBuffer pixelBuffer = await renderTarget.GetPixelsAsync();

            DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(pixelBuffer);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[pixelBuffer.Length];
            dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
            ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            localSettings.Values["thumbnail"] = bytes;
            localSettings.Values["test setting"] = "a device specific setting";
            Frame.GoBack();
 }
```

I don't know how to return that byte array and string directly. So I use LocalSettings to store parameters, but it will give below error if data is too large :

> The size of the state manager setting value has exceeded the limit.

So how to return data correctly? Do I need to save the data as a file and only return the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to return data correctly when navigate Back in UWP

`GoBack` doesn't pass a parameter so you'll need to pass the data through an outside channel.

One possibility would be to make Action parameter, pass it to `DetailPage` from `MainPage`.  And call this action before  call `GoBack` from `DetailPage`.

For example

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _backAction = new Action<byte[]>((para) =>
        {
          // get bytes here with para.
        });

    }

    private Action<byte[]> _backAction;
    private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage),_backAction);
    }
}
```

**DetailPage**

```
public sealed partial class DetailPage : Page
{
    public DetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Action<byte[]> backAction;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        backAction = e.Parameter as Action<byte[]>;
    }

    private async void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTarget.RenderAsync(this);
        IBuffer pixelBuffer = await renderTarget.GetPixelsAsync();

        DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(pixelBuffer);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[pixelBuffer.Length];
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
        backAction(bytes);
        Frame.GoBack();
    }
}
```